# Why my file characters are not reading and key is not generating?

Tags: c++, file, size, ascii

Here is my program. The purpose is to find the **no. of characters** in file and **sum of all ASCII values** **of characters** and then **concatenate** the no. of characters+Sum of ASCII values. It will be a key and should be written at the end of file. So that if someone change the file text, the regenerating key will be different from previous and the program will notify that "file is changed by someone". 
Problem is that my key is not generating correctly. It writes **%** instead of **%38757483** which means 38 is total characters and 757483 is total sum of ASCII. Following is the complete code without any syntax error:

```
////By Zeshan from VU
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


////function prototypes///

void menu(std::ifstream &file, string filename);      //to show the menu of multiple options
void openFile(string filename);
void findSize(std::ifstream &file, string filename);  //to find the sum of all characters in file
void findASCII(char allWords[], int size, std::ifstream &file, string filename); // to find the sum of all character's ASCII values in file
void protectFile(std::ifstream &file, string filename);
void checkFile(std::ifstream &file, string filename);
void key(int size, char ASCII, std::ifstream &file, string filename);    // this function will generate the key by combining size figure and ASCII sum followed by % character
void reKey(int size, char ASCII, std::ifstream &file, string filename, string oldKey);  //regenerate key for matching with previous one
void reFindASCII(char allWordsBeforeKey, int size, std::ifstream &file, string filename, string oldKey);
void putKeyinFile(string fName, string key, std::ifstream &file);   // this function will write the key at file's end line

void reKey(int size, char ASCII, std::ifstream &file, string filename, string oldKey)
{
    string key;
     char cSize =  size;
     key=cSize+ASCII;
     key='%'+key;

     if(key == oldKey)
         cout<<"The contents of file are not changed after protection. \n";
     else
         cout<<"Alert! The contents of file are changed after protection. \n";

     system("pause");

}

void checkFile(std::ifstream &file, string filename){
     int i=0, flag=0, keyPositioninFile=0;
     char word[100]="";      
     char allWords[10000]="";   
     string strAllWords="", oldKey="";
     int totalCharacters=0;
     int totalCharactersBeforeKey=0;
     char allWordsBeforeKey=0;
     string strAllWordsBeforeKey="";

     while(!file.eof()) //This loop will collect all words from file
     {
               file >> word;  

               strcat(word," ");
               strcat(allWords,word);  
     }


     strAllWords=allWords;
     totalCharacters=strAllWords.size();
     while(i != totalCharacters)
     {
         if(strAllWords[i] == '%')
         {
            flag=1;
         }
         i++;
     }



         if(flag==0)
         {
             cout<<"Your file is not protected. First protect it using option 1. \n\n";
             menu(file, filename);
         }



    i=0;
     if(flag) //If the key is already generated in the file
     {

         while(strAllWords[i] != '%')
         {
             allWordsBeforeKey=allWordsBeforeKey+strAllWords[i];
             i++;
         }
         strAllWordsBeforeKey=allWordsBeforeKey;

         i=0;
         while(strAllWords[i] == '%') //To note that where old key is located in the file
         {
             keyPositioninFile=i;
         }

         for(int j=keyPositioninFile; j<=strAllWordsBeforeKey.size(); j++)
         {
         oldKey[j]=strAllWordsBeforeKey[j]; 
         }

         totalCharactersBeforeKey=strAllWordsBeforeKey.size();
         reFindASCII(allWordsBeforeKey, totalCharactersBeforeKey, file, filename, oldKey);
     }   
}

void menu(std::ifstream &file, string filename)
{
     int option=0;
     cout<<"Operations on text file: \n";
     cout<<"1. Protect my text file \n";
     cout<<"2. Check security of my text file \n\n";
     cout<<"Enter your choice (1/2): ";
     cin>>option;
     if(option==1) 
                   protectFile(file, filename);

     else if(option==2) 
                   checkFile(file, filename);
     else 
                   cout<<"Error: option selection is invalid";

}

void openFile(string filename)
{
     ifstream theFile;
     theFile.open(filename);
     if(!theFile){
                   cout<<"Cant open input file named "<<filename;
                   system("pause>nul");
                   exit(1);
                 }
     menu(theFile, filename);
}

void findSize(std::ifstream &file, string filename)
{
     char word[100]="";      
     char allWords[10000]="";   
     string strAllWords="";
     int totalCharacters=0; 

     while(!file.eof())
     {
               file >> word;
               cout<<word<<" ";   
               strcat(word," ");
               strcat(allWords,word);           
     }

     strAllWords=allWords;
     totalCharacters = strAllWords.size();

     findASCII(allWords, totalCharacters, file, filename);    
}

void findASCII(char allWords[], int size, std::ifstream &file, string filename)
{
    int i=0, totalASCIIofChars=0;

    while(i != size)
    {
           totalASCIIofChars  = totalASCIIofChars + allWords[i];
           i++;  
    } 

    key(size, totalASCIIofChars, file, filename);
}

void reFindASCII(char allWordsBeforeKey, int size, std::ifstream &file, string filename, string oldKey)
{
    int i=0, totalASCIIofCharsBeforeKey=0;
  string strAllWordsBeforeKey=&allWordsBeforeKey;
    while(i != size)
    {
           totalASCIIofCharsBeforeKey  = totalASCIIofCharsBeforeKey + strAllWordsBeforeKey[i];
           i++;  
    } 

    reKey(size, totalASCIIofCharsBeforeKey, file, filename, oldKey);
}

void key(int size, char ASCII, std::ifstream &file, string filename)
{

     string key="";
     char cSize = size;
     key=cSize+ASCII;
    // cout<<"Key is: "<<size; /////////////////PROBLEM HERE////////// 
     key='%'+key;
  //   strcat(&key, "%");
     putKeyinFile(filename, key, file);
     cout<<"Your file is protected now. \n";

     system("pause");

}

void protectFile(std::ifstream &file, string filename)
{
     int i=0;
     char word[100]="";      
     char allWords[10000]="";   
     string strAllWords="";
     while(!file.eof())
     {
               file >> word;  

               strcat(word," ");
               strcat(allWords,word);           
     }
     strAllWords=allWords;

     while(i != strAllWords.size())
     {
               if(allWords[i] == '%')
               {
                       cout<<"File is already protected, first protect it by using option 1";
                       menu(file, filename);
               }

               i++;
     }
     findSize(file, filename);                                          

}

void putKeyinFile(string fName, string key, std::ifstream &file)
{
     ofstream oFile;
     oFile.open(fName, ios::app);
     oFile<<key;
     oFile.close();
     file.close();
}

int main()
{        
   // char fName[30];
    string fName;
    cout<<"Enter the name of text file in current directory: ";
    cin>>fName; 
    openFile(fName);


}
```

Comment: TL;DR. Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note: Read the description of tags! C and C++ are different languages. Your code is _not_ C code!

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an [MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Use debugger to check where the bug is.

Comment: The requirements you presented makes no delineation for words.  Why are you separating words?

Comment: Stick with `std::string` for muli-character items or `char *`.  Don't mix them.  I recommend using `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a smaller version of your program, probably using features you don't know about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
using std::cin;
using std::uint64_t;
using std::ostringstream;

void Pause(void)
{
  cout << "\nPaused. Press Enter to continue.\n";
  cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
}

int main(void)
{
  ifstream  input("my_datafile.txt", std::ios::binary) // prevent translations
  if (!input)
  {
    cerr << "Error opening \"my_datafile.txt\" as input.\n";
    Pause();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  uint64_t chars_in_file = 0U;
  uint64_t ascii_sum = 0U;
  static const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;
  static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  while (input.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)
  {
    unsigned int bytes_read = input.gcount();
    chars_in_file += bytes_read;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes_read; ++i)
    {
      ascii_sum += buffer[i];
    }
  }
  ostringstream formatting_stream;
  formatting_stream << chars_in_file << ascii_sum;
  const std::string key = formatting_stream.str();
  cout << "The key is: " << key << "\n";
  Pause();
  return 0;
}
```

I don't see the need for a lot of the stuff you have in your code.